# AWS Cloudformation Template Parameters for SAM Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

In SAM Local's `template.yaml`, is it possible to define a set of parameters such that they become Cloudformation parameters?

The reason I want this is I'd like to create a [Launch Stack Url](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/construct-your-own-launch-stack-url/) that allows the user to provide Cloudformation parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit this looks possible. You need to define a root level `Parameters` as you would for a normal cloudformation template. Hence here is what mine looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 300

...

Parameters:
  MyUserParameter:
    Type: String
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://blah/blah
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FOO: bar
      Events:
        CatchAll:
          Properties:
            Method: GET
            Path: /hello
          Type: Api
      Handler: hello-world
      Runtime: go1.x
      Tracing: Active
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

Answer (score 0):

As n00b said

> You need to define a root level Parameters

But those parameters become sorted alphabetically in the configuration.
If you want to organize them as it is in your link, you have to use Metadata:

```
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Name of your parameter group
        Parameters:
          - Parameter
    ParameterLabels:
      ParameterName:
        default: Complete name of your parameter with spaces if you want
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudformation-interface.html